# Access Env variables within php

Tags: php, apache, bash

How to access environment variables located in  ~/.bash_profile from within PHP running with apache localhost (Mac)? I tried getenv() but no luck. Is there anything I need to change with php.ini?

Comment: Use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: You seem to expect your Apache server process to load an environment init script from your user's home directory. Unless you have made changes to the system, Apache runs as another user.

Comment: @dekts I have used getenv but I get bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

Example from the PHP website:

```
<?php
    // Example use of getenv()
    $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

    // Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV)
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    // Safely get the value of an environment variable, ignoring whether 
    // or not it was set by a SAPI or has been changed with putenv
    $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR', true) ?: getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')
?>
```

Comment: I tried the following <?php
    // Example use of getenv()
    $ip = getenv('USER');
 echo $ip;
    // Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV)
    $ip = $_SERVER['USER'];
    echo $ip;
    // Safely get the value of an environment variable, ignoring whether 
    // or not it was set by a SAPI or has been changed with putenv
    $ip = getenv('USER', true) ?: getenv('USER');

    echo $ip;
?>    it dint print any. I was expecting it to print by system user. If echo $USER in my cli i would get vinayemmadi

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SERVER Variables and $_ENV to get all you need. Do an print_r of each of them to see what they contain.

Comment: first check on your command prompt and see, if you're echo the environment variables. if they dont work, then, obviously apache will not show environment variables.